# Label in Custom TableViewCell can't be multiline or wrap

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I tried to make the cell in my custom `tableViewCell` class to be multi-line and wrap.
I read my Q&A here and follow the instructions but still unable to find a solution.

I can adjust the dynamic height per content length but still unable to make the 
Here is my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomItemCell"];
   if(cell == nil){
      cell = [[CustomItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:@"CustomItemCell"];

      //I set lineBreakMode of cell.postLabel to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping 
      // and set numberofLines = 0 ; 
      cell.postLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
      cell.postLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    }
    CustomItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   //postLabel is the label that I want to be multiline and wordwrap  
   // postLabel get an NSString from [item post] 
   [[cell postLabel] setText:[item post]];

   [[cell timeLabel] setText:[item time]];
   [[cell distanceLabel] setText:[item distance]];
   [[cell thumbnailView] setImage:[item thumbnail]];

   return cell;
}
```

I created the `CustomItemCell.xib` file. And actually, I also set the line to zero and the linebreak to wordwrap in interface builder but it is not shown as I expected.

Comment: labels can be multiline and wrap if you set the label height as per its contents

Comment: Easiest way to try if you have something wrong with the `postLabel` is to call `[[cell postLabel] sizeToFit]` after you set the text. Also be careful to add `postLabel` to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: The height is already set but it does not change anything.

Comment: Marko, I have my cell set in CustomItemCell.xib. Do I have to add it to the content view again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
[cell.postLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Already tried. But didn't work...  I put it below     [[cell postLabel] setText:[item post]];  line.

Comment: I found the problem. The interface builder has "Use autolayout" enabled. I disabled this option and sizeToFit works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

set cell style as shown below for multi-line,

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

check it..